# unable to ping my win7 computer from an another computer in different subnet while I could do the opposite

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking, routing, subnet

subnet **A**(192.168.137.0/24) has **P**(192.168.137.1) and **Q**(192.168.137.2) computers

subnet **B**(192.168.7.0/24) has **Q**(192.168.7.1) and **R**(192.168.7.2) computers

**P** is my windows 7 computer connected to internet over interface 10 and connected to **Q** over interface 25

**Q**(Linux) was set up to route packets between **A** and **B**. Its default gateway is set to **P**

**R**(Linux)'s default gateway was set to **Q**.

I was able to route packets from **P**(Win7) to subnet **B** via **Q** using

```
route -p add 192.168.7.0 mask 255.255.255.0 192.168.137.2 metric 1 if 25
```

now I could ping **R**(192.168.7.2) from **P**(my win7 computer) but I couldn't ping **P** from **R**! I could ping www.google.com from **R**!!

## C:\Windows\system32>route print

```
Interface List
 11...00 1c 23 29 25 7e ......Broadcom NetXtreme 57xx Gigabit Controller
 10...00 1c bf 9d 91 38 ......Intel(R) PRO/Wireless 3945ABG Network Connect
 25...00 50 56 c0 00 01 ......VMware Virtual Ethernet Adapter for VMnet1
 26...00 50 56 c0 00 08 ......VMware Virtual Ethernet Adapter for VMnet8
  1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
 21...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
 17...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
 23...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft 6to4 Adapter
 18...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2
 22...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #3
 24...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #4
 20...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #5
===========================================================================

IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0    124.123.192.1   124.123.199.79     20
    124.123.192.0    255.255.192.0         On-link    124.123.199.79    276
   124.123.199.79  255.255.255.255         On-link    124.123.199.79    276
  124.123.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link    124.123.199.79    276
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
      192.168.7.0    255.255.255.0    192.168.137.2    192.168.137.1     21
     192.168.18.0    255.255.255.0         On-link      192.168.18.1    276
     192.168.18.1  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.18.1    276
   192.168.18.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.18.1    276
    192.168.137.0    255.255.255.0         On-link     192.168.137.1    276
    192.168.137.1  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.137.1    276
  192.168.137.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.137.1    276
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link    124.123.199.79    276
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link     192.168.137.1    276
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link      192.168.18.1    276
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link    124.123.199.79    276
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.137.1    276
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.18.1    276
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  Network Address          Netmask  Gateway Address  Metric
      192.168.7.0    255.255.255.0    192.168.137.2       1
===========================================================================

IPv6 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
 If Metric Network Destination      Gateway
 23   1275 ::/0                     2002:c058:6301::c058:6301
 23   1274 ::/0                     2002:c058:6301::1
  1    306 ::1/128                  On-link
 23   1025 2002::/16                On-link
 23    281 2002:7c7b:c74f::7c7b:c74f/128
                                    On-link
 11    276 fe80::/64                On-link
 25    276 fe80::/64                On-link
 26    276 fe80::/64                On-link
 11    276 fe80::7456:ab7f:70fa:3029/128
                                    On-link
 25    276 fe80::7c8a:b566:2a17:ccdb/128
                                    On-link
 26    276 fe80::e12e:9f18:a010:b07b/128
                                    On-link
  1    306 ff00::/8                 On-link
 11    276 ff00::/8                 On-link
 25    276 ff00::/8                 On-link
 26    276 ff00::/8                 On-link
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None
```

Answer (score 0):

The routing between the two subnets should be done on Q. You should have a route from NIC1 to NIC2 and a route vice versa. You then wouldn't need the route on P, all computers would be able to ping each other and have access to the internet, using P as gateway.

You didn't tell us the flavor of Linux running on Q. You can find static routing information for your Linux flavor via Google.

Comment: Q is ubuntu. I configure iptables to forward traffic A to B and B to A. Since R is able to connect to Internet and P is able to ssh into R I can say that traffic is being forwarded both ways by Q. But some how P(win7) is dropping packets that are destined to it from the other subnet. Wireshark on P shows the ping requests from R and there are no responses from P.

Comment: `207 175.808410000 192.168.7.2 192.168.137.1 ICMP 98 Echo (ping) request  id=0x04b6, seq=2/512, ttl=63 (no response found!)` is the wireshark summary of a ping request from R. I think it got to do some thing with policies... I never understand them :)

Comment: may be only ICMP packets are dropped? are TCP packets are allowed?? I should check It by running some webserver on P

Comment: It starts to sound more like a firewall issue. To test, disable the firewall on the P, retry the ping and see if it goes through. If it does, you need to allow connections (starting with ICMP) in the Windows Firewall of P.
PS: I love this welcome to the group. My answer deleted even though it is a valid one, a totally different solution than I offered firstly. Just deleted, doesn't matter if it could be the solution, no warning, no request to remove and post it in a different location. So if the solution in this comment proves to be the right one, will the comment be voted up? Yes, I'm pissed!